# Java exception: why my program is not terminating?

Tags: java, exception

When I run my simple **code** and enter **char** instead of integer value which was supposed to be Entered.

Program, listed below is supposed to be terminated after printing **"error please Enter integer value"**.

But this code, also printing the line after Occurrence of **error**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter value integer ");
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            int a = sn.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex){
            System.out.println("error please enter integer value");
        }
        System.out.println("not terminating");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this code, also printing the line after Occurrence of error

Because it is out side of try-catch, that is the advantage of exception handling.

Exception handling *prevents the abnormal termination of program* due to run time error. And that is what happened.

#### See also

- [exception handing docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is terminating, it just prints out the System.out first. This is as expected - it jumps into the catch block, and then continues.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("enter value integer ");
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        int a = sn.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("error please enter integer value");
        // you are catching input mis match here 
        // exception will catch and program continues
    }
    System.out.println("not terminating"); // this is out side the try-catch
```

So you will get this line in your out put too.

Answer (score 0):

After entering the `catch` block, flow continues on, so the next line to execute is the bottom print.

If you want to terminate from within the `catch`:

```
try {
    int a = sn.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("error please enter integer value");
    return; // program will end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be terminated you need to re-throw the exception e.g.:

```
System.out.println("enter value integer ");
Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int a = sn.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("error please enter integer value");

    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}

System.out.println("not terminating"); // this is out side the try-catch
```

That way the last system output would not be printed and you would get a stacktrace instead.